# usb ethernet adapter interface not working in ubuntu 21.10 in virtual machine

Tags: usb, ethernet, connection, adapter

I have the following scenario: I have as a host operating system Windows 10 x64 and as guest operating system Ubuntu 21.10 in virtual machine.
I want to use an USB-C/ethernet adapter 3.0 in Linux and also add a VLAN interface. When I try to make virtual machine with VMware workstation the USB device isn't found in `lsusb` while with VirtualBox the USB device is found but the connection is grayed out. If I run `nmcli device status` the connection row is shown but the status is unavailable. How can I fix this issue?

edit: the adapter does not work with the virtualbox machine either and
I installed Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack.
In the following images are the settings:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

`nmcli` doesn't work any more. The interface is shown as unavailable and `lsusb` doesn't show the USB device.

edit 2:
I don't know how but I have seen USBs from guest system... the following is the output of `lsusb` and `nmcli`:

```
fra@fra-Linux:~/Scrivania$ sudo lsusb
[sudo] password di fra: 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
fra@fra-Linux:~/Scrivania$ sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0b95:1790 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88179 Gigabit Ethernet
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
fra@fra-Linux:~/Scrivania$ nmcli device status
DEVICE           TYPE      STATE            CONNECTION             
enp0s3           ethernet  collegato        Connessione via cavo 1 
enx000ec6556c66  ethernet  non disponibile  --                     
enx000ec6556.83  vlan      non disponibile  --                     
lo               loopback  non gestito      --                     
fra@fra-Linux:~/Scrivania$
```

state "non disponibile" means "unavailable" or "not available"

state "collegato" means "linked"

state "non gestito" means "not managed"

In the prompt, "Scrivania" means desktop

In the following 2 screenshots you can see that connection Ethernet 1 isn't shown to the desktop applet:

[image]

[image]

Comment: VMWare, Virtualbox, other? Please add detail about it above. Edit!

Comment: what detail do You need?

Comment: "everything". you have not stated enough detail to allow a reasonable analysis.

Comment: Hmm, on re-reading; Virtualbox! Now include the text that "nmcli" displays, mark it as code. Others might have to chime in to identify the needed driver, id that is what is missing. You MIGHT also need the install the "Guest additions" if not already done. Also USB settings might need tweaking.

Comment: Hmm... "VirtualBox Extension Pack" required for USB 2 and 3

Comment: @Hannu there are other detail necessary to analyze problem?